# Text and Checked Rectangle Detection in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, text, ocr, detection

I have a document from which I need to detect which item is checked. It is greatly appreciated if we can extract the corresponding text.

Below I am attaching the sample doc.

[Sample Doc to scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zieuz.jpg)

As per above sample I need to fetch the selected item i.e. Inspected and Expiry date only.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's an android OCR library (which is now deprecated by ML Kit) and works well - here's a tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0 . The checkbox may require extending the library.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If you noticed I want to fetch only the Item which is checked. I guess Google vision detects texts in this scenario.